# Protect PHP in TinyMCE

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE for template generating.I have a script

```
<img src="<?php echo $img_link; ?>" />
```

But, When I save and reopen the source code view, it convert my PHP code to `lt;&amp;` or `&lt;!--mce:protected`

I am using `protect`

```
protect: [ 
  /\<\/?(if|endif)\>/g,
  /\<xsl\:[^>]+\>/g,
  /<\?php.*?\?>/g , 
  /<\?php[\s\S]*?\?>/g,
  /\"\<\?php[\s\S]*?\?\>\"/g
]
```

When is use `<p><?php echo $name; ?></p>` it works fine but not in Double Quotes of HTML Elements.

Any guess how to fix this.?